# Changing gradient background color by item in an adapter

Tags: android, mobile, gradient

I wan to create something like this. I'm want to use it in android kotlin application.
https://dribbble.com/shots/3830441-To-Do-App
Do you have any idea how to change background color soothly like you can see in that link ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#376F9D"
    android:centerColor="#4E9EB4"
    android:endColor="#4F9FB5"
    android:angle="0"
    android:type="linear"/>
</shape>
```

Then use it as a back ground on the root element on the layout of your activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient">

<RelativeLayout
    android:paddingTop="56dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for things like this:

- **ViewPager** for the UI
- Set **onPageChangeListener()** for your ViewPager to detect when your ViewPager has been changed its screen
- Use **ViewPager.setBackgroundColor()** api to change ViewPager background during the change
- Use **ArgbEvaluator.evaluate(positionOffSet, yourCurrentColorValue, yourNextColorValue)** to get the smoothy animated color value for your above **ViewPager.setBackgroundColor()**

For more reference on the full solution, you can google it or you can look for something like this: http://kubaspatny.github.io/2014/09/18/viewpager-background-transition/

Kotlin is probably having similar way to solve this problem.